# Google ORTools VRPTW with start and end locations for routes

Tags: python, or-tools

I have tried to implements start and end locations for routes on VRPTW example following ufficial guide of ortools.

in data, i have add:

```
data['starts'] = [1, 2, 15, 16]
data['ends'] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And i have changed RoutingIndexManager to:

```
   # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['starts'],
        data['ends'])
```

This is my code after join that instruction with original VRPTW example:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def create_data_model():
  """Stores the data for the problem."""
  data = {}
  data['time_matrix'] = [
      [0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3, 6, 2, 3, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 9, 7],
      [6, 0, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4, 8, 8, 13, 7, 5, 8, 12, 10, 14],
      [9, 8, 0, 11, 10, 6, 3, 9, 5, 8, 4, 15, 14, 13, 9, 18, 9],
      [8, 3, 11, 0, 1, 7, 10, 6, 10, 10, 14, 6, 7, 9, 14, 6, 16],
      [7, 2, 10, 1, 0, 6, 9, 4, 8, 9, 13, 4, 6, 8, 12, 8, 14],
      [3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 7, 9, 7, 7, 6, 12, 8],
      [6, 8, 3, 10, 9, 2, 0, 6, 2, 5, 4, 12, 10, 10, 6, 15, 5],
      [2, 4, 9, 6, 4, 3, 6, 0, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 10],
      [3, 8, 5, 10, 8, 2, 2, 4, 0, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 3, 13, 6],
      [2, 8, 8, 10, 9, 2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 5],
      [6, 13, 4, 14, 13, 7, 4, 8, 4, 4, 0, 10, 9, 8, 4, 13, 4],
      [6, 7, 15, 6, 4, 9, 12, 5, 9, 6, 10, 0, 1, 3, 7, 3, 10],
      [4, 5, 14, 7, 6, 7, 10, 4, 8, 5, 9, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 8],
      [4, 8, 13, 9, 8, 7, 10, 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6],
      [5, 12, 9, 14, 12, 6, 6, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 9, 2],
      [9, 10, 18, 6, 8, 12, 15, 8, 13, 9, 13, 3, 4, 5, 9, 0, 9],
      [7, 14, 9, 16, 14, 8, 5, 10, 6, 5, 4, 10, 8, 6, 2, 9, 0],
  ]
  data['time_windows'] = [
      (0, 5),  # depot
      (7, 12),  # 1
      (10, 15),  # 2
      (16, 18),  # 3
      (10, 13),  # 4
      (0, 5),  # 5
      (5, 10),  # 6
      (0, 4),  # 7
      (5, 10),  # 8
      (0, 3),  # 9
      (10, 16),  # 10
      (10, 15),  # 11
      (0, 5),  # 12
      (5, 10),  # 13
      (7, 8),  # 14
      (10, 15),  # 15
      (11, 15),  # 16
  ]
  data['num_vehicles'] = 4

  data['starts'] = [0, 2, 0, 0]
  data['ends'] = [1, 0, 0, 0]

  return data

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment):
    """Prints assignment on console."""
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    total_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2}) -> '.format(
                manager.IndexToNode(index), assignment.Min(time_var),
                assignment.Max(time_var))
            index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2})\n'.format(
            manager.IndexToNode(index), assignment.Min(time_var),
            assignment.Max(time_var))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}min\n'.format(
            assignment.Min(time_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += assignment.Min(time_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))

def main():
    """Solve the VRP with time windows."""
    data = create_data_model()

    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data['time_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['starts'], data['ends'])

    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    time = 'Time'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        30,  # allow waiting time
        30,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
    # Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
        if location_idx == 0:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data['time_windows'][0][0],
                                                data['time_windows'][0][1])
    for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    if assignment:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Now, if i try to execute code, python exit with following error: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I have tried to isolate bug, and seem to be related with time window constraints for each location except depot.

If i remove:

```
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
```

Code works without errors, but obviously without time windows constraints.

I don't understood where is the problem and how to solve. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried set "maximum time per vehicle" to a larger value? Like in documentation.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't forget to either: turn this answer into a comment when you get commenting privilege / or make it a full answer as in [answer]

Answer (score 0):

maby the time windows and start-end point pair constraints due to the probl

Comment: maby the time windows and start-end point pair constraints lead the problem infeasiable

Comment: Welcome. Please don't forget to either: turn this answer into a comment when you get commenting privilege / or make it a full answer as in [answer]